# Google.Drive.Api Oauth 2 Credientials in Xamarin android application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to read a file from google drive using my xamarin android application using google.drive.api, the latter requests Google Oauth2 ID credentials for Android to be authorized to access Google drive.

The debugging stops here :

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "My-Client-ID",
                    ClientSecret = null
                },
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

and raises and exception :

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A46401%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.readonly" for authorization. See inner exception for details.)'

**Note :** It worked fine when trying it on a Desktop console application using an Oauth ID for desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` was designed for use with installed applications only.  The [google .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client) does not support Xamarin auth.  As can be seen on the README for the library.

[image]

You will not be able to use this library for authentication.  Your going to have to code the authorization yourself. I have done it in the past for a client it is doable.

Comment: Thank you for the information, authentication didn't work indeed, but i managed to find a solution to my problem by sharing my file to "everyone with the link" then using the file ID was enough to access and read data from it.

Comment: just remember there is a limit to the number of times per day that share with link can be used.